# Hadoop MRUnit throws exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to write some unit tests for my hadoop MR job and get following exception. This is the first time I am using MRUnit, so I am not really sure whats happening here.

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext, but interface was expected
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockContextWrapper.createCommon(MockContextWrapper.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockMapContextWrapper.create(MockMapContextWrapper.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.mock.MockMapContextWrapper.<init>(MockMapContextWrapper.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver.run(MapDriver.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.runTest(MapDriverBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:137)
```

My actual code looks very simple

```
private MapDriver<Text, Text, Text, Text> mapDriver = MapDriver.newMapDriver(mapper);
private ReduceDriver<Text, Text, Text, Text> reduceDriver = ReduceDriver.newReduceDriver(reducer);
private MapReduceDriver<Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text> driver = MapReduceDriver.newMapReduceDriver(mapper, reducer);

@Test
public void testMapper() {
    mapDriver.withInput(new Text("1"), new Text("Line 1"));
    mapDriver.withOutput(new Text("1"), new Text("Line 1"));
    mapDriver.runTest();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

As you can see in [here](https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.apache.mrunit~~~~), there are two classifiers in mrunit 0.9. And there are some problems using mrunit under Java 7 environment.

Perhaps, you are deveoping with hadoop 1.0.x and added only one of two classifiers in your pom.xml file. The solution is easy: **Just add another one, like described below.** That's all.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
        <classifier>hadoop1</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I think this bug would be solved in next release, but I can not be convinced.

Comment: This weird bug is still there with <version>1.0.0</version>

Comment: Using <classifier>hadoop2</classifier> fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error tends to happen if the version of MRUnit you are using was built against a different release of Hadoop than then code you are testing. In this particular case I believe TaskInputOutputContext was changed from an abstract class to an interface in 0.21.

So, it's probably the case that you are using 0.21 while the MRUnit version your using built against 0.20. I would simply work to get the versions sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

MRUnit has two release package for Hadoop 1.x and Hadoop 2.x. You should make sure the mrunit version equals to hadoop version.